# Jquery/Js Variable Plus Variable Output Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to read a variable txt from other variables that are basically from a counter of such.

example:

```
var txt0 = "this is txt 0"
var txt1 = "this is txt 1"
var txt2 = "this is txt 2"

counter = 0 // 1,2 or 3 etc
var a = (var+counter);  // this line output : var0;or var3 etc
$(h1').text(a);
console.log(a);
//answer I want is : this is text 0 or 1 or 2;
```

I tried to create a basic sample to demonstrate my issue, I need to use this format as a lot of the other code is dependent on the dynamic of counters various checks for other content

Comment: Why don't you store them inside of an `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cad do it with this code: `var a = window['txt'+counter];`

```js
var txt0 = "this is txt 0"
var txt1 = "this is txt 1"
var txt2 = "this is txt 2"

counter = 0; // 1,2 or 3 etc
var a = window['txt'+counter];
$('h1').text(a);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1></h1>
```

But of course using array or JSON object will be more efficient

Comment: For some reason only worked once I removed the vars for each TXT. Thanks for putting it in a simple form for me to relate.

Comment: did I post something else? :D

Comment: @Sanjay Nishad your code doesn't seem to work: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpmxfnts/1/) ;P

Comment: if my code doesn't work, how is working yours? both are same :D
btw `window['txt'+counter]` is not working with jsFiddle, doesn't matters mine or yours :)

Comment: They aren't the same: `window['txt'+counter]` vs `window["var"+counter]` - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpmxfnts/3/) ^^

Answer (score 1):

you can access using `window`

```
var a = window["var"+counter];  // this line output : var0;or var3 etc
```

but you should use an array or JOSN object

```
var obj = {txt0 :"this is txt 0", txt1: "this is txt 1", txt2 = "this is txt 2"}
```

and access like

```
obj["var"+counter]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = ["this is text 0", "this is text 1", "this is text 2"];

var counter = 0;
/* You should make sure counter is within [0; txt.length - 1 ] */
$('h1').text(txt[counter]);
```